# Insert text into mail body php

Tags: php, oop, sendmail

this is my code

```
class Email {
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $subject;
    public $textarea;
    public $to = "stereoshoots@gmail.com";
    public $header;

    function __construct($name, $email, $subject, $textarea) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->textarea = $textarea;
        $this->header = "From:$this->email \r\n";
        $this->header .= "Имя: $this->name \r\n";
        $this->sendEmail();
    }

    public function sendEmail(){
        if(mail ($this->to,$this->subject,$this->textarea,$this->header)) {
            echo "Отправлено";
        }
        else {
            echo "Ошибка";
        }
    }
}
$obj = new Email($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['textarea']);
```

I want to have Client Name: John Doe in beginning of every mail. How can i do that via headers?

Thanks

Comment: Just as a sidenote, I wouldremove `sendEmail()` from the constructor - a constructor's responsiblity is to construct an object. Side effects like sending an email do not belong there, and will be unexpected by people who use that class.

Comment: when you mean beginning where within the message (textarea)? If so could you not prepend this prior to assigning it?

Comment: Okay i did that, how can i insert text into mail message?

Comment: Yes in the beginning of message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to do it via headers?

Why not create a new var

for html mail

`$this->message=$name."<br><br>".$textarea;`

or for plain text

`$this->message=$name."\n\n".$textarea;`

and then change your `sendEmail()` to

`if(mail ($this->to,$this->subject,$this->message,$this->header)) {`

I may be missing something of what your trying to achieve, let me know if im off track here.